# Want to make a view like this in android

Tags: android, layout, material-design

I want to make a view like this in android :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I did but i don't know the term exactly to search for but at least i know its view pager thats scrolling inside but no idea how to achieve whole view as shown in pic.

Answer (score 0):

Use CollapsingToolbarLayout

---

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <!--app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"-->
            <!--app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"-->
            <!--app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"-->

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/cover"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/prflProfilepic"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/prfle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp"/>



            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```